# Simultaneous equations of cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations

Can anyone give me pointers for solving these simultaneous equations?
$$\cos\pi x=0$$
$$\cos(\pi x)^2=0$$
There doesn't seem to be much information out there about how to work with $\cos(\pi x)^2$. I tried using the Taylor expansion $\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(x)^{2n}$, which gave me
$$\cos\pi x=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(\pi x)^{2n}=0$$
$$\cos(\pi x)^2=\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(\pi x)^{4n}=0$$
I divided by $\pi^2$ to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{4n}=0$$
...but then I got stuck. I made the (clearly wrong) assumption that
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\equiv\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞ x^{2n}\right)$$
This gave me
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ x^{2n}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ x^{4n}=0$$
Neither of these equations have real-number solutions.

Effectively, I have simultaneous equations in the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ f(x)g(x)=0$$
and I don't know how to proceed. Perhaps the whole Taylor series idea is a red herring?

I'd really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, Taylor series aren't needed at all.
$$\cos\pi x=0\iff x=n-\frac12\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$
$$\cos(\pi x)^2=\cos\pi(\pi x^2)=0\iff\pi x^2=m-\frac12\qquad m\in\mathbb Z$$
$$\pi x^2=\pi\left(n-\frac12\right)^2=m-\frac12$$
$$\pi=\frac{m-\frac12}{\left(n-\frac12\right)^2}$$
But $\pi$ is irrational and the denominator is never zero, so there are no solutions to the simultaneous equations.

Comment: I'm hunting for the "answered" button...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward It's the tick you see below the up and down buttons to the left of my answer. Click it and it will turn green, marking it as accepted.